# TypeScript - How do you add comments?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm a TS newbie...
I have the following code: I would like to comment out the logo. I have tried adding "//" and '/*' but appears do nothing.

Tried this:  `//  <LogoComponent classes={{container: style.logoContainer, svg: style.logoSvg}} />`

Any ideas

```
export const HomePageComponent: React.StatelessComponent<HomePageProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={style.container}>

**COMMENT THIS LINE OUT ?**
      <LogoComponent classes={{container: style.logoContainer, svg: style.logoSvg}} />


      <div className={style.main}>
        <CaptionComponent />
        <SearchInput         
          searchValue={props.searchValue}
          onSearchSubmit={props.onSearchSubmit}
          onSearchUpdate={props.onSearchUpdate}
        />
        <SearchButton onClick={props.onSearchSubmit}/>
          </div>

          <FooterComponent className={style.footer} />


    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
   { /*<LogoComponent classes={{container: style.logoContainer, svg: style.logoSvg}} /> */ }
```

[Wes Bos - How to comment in React JSX](https://wesbos.com/react-jsx-comments/)

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-famrwu)

Comment: When I add that. the build fails

Comment: log is too long to paste

Comment: @Jon can you create a demo base of your code on stackblitz and check the demo